# coding many to many relationship in c++ sqlite3

Tags: c++, sqlite

I trying to code a many to many relationship in c++ sqlite3.

in the diagram below,

[image: diagram]

- managers can add many job opportunities.
- jobs opportunities is being add by many managers

  my create table statements

  ```
   "CREATE TABLE Manager(" \
   "manager_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"\
   "name varchar(45) NOT NULL);"

   "CREATE TABLE jobs ("
   "jobId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"\
   "jobTitle varchar(45) NOT NULL);"

   "CREATE TABLE Add ("
   "manager_id,jobId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"\
   "date varchar(45) NOT NULL,"\
   "FOREIGN KEY(manager_id) REFERENCES Manager(manager_id),"\
   "FOREIGN KEY(job_id) REFERENCES jobs(job_id));";
  ```

my manager table is populated with the following information

```
1|john
2|bob
```

let's say manager john has added two jobs,jobTitle jobA and jobB

then my insert statement code will look like this.http://pastebin.com/0E8CzPgX

then my jobs tables is populated with the following information

```
1|jobA
2|jobB
```

the final step is to take the id of john(manager id = 1) and the two jobsId(1,2) and add it inside 
the add table. I don't have an idea of how should I code
so that the add table will become like this.

add table

```
manager_id|job_id|date
    1     |  1   |30-01-2014
    1     |  2   |30-01-2014
```

please advise.thanks

Comment: i don't see anything related to C++ here

Comment: I know how to code the insertion of jobTitle into jobs table.http://pastebin.com/0E8CzPgX but I am not sure how to take the id of john and the the twosJobsId and insert it into the add table.

Comment: Please note that in the `Add` table, `manager_id` is *not* part of the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Add(manager_id,jobId,date) VALUES (?,?,?);";
```

?

Your problem seems to be that you defined jobID to be the primary key of the table Add, which you don't need.

```
jobId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NUL
```

A common approach to many-to-many relations in a database is to include an intermediate table.

This intermediate table (let's call it Manager_jobs) would have at least 2 columns, both referring to other tables via foreign key. The first attribute would be the primary key of Manager, the second one the primary key of jobs.

Each time you add a job, you just add an entry to Manager_jobs with the foreign keys respectively.

So, Manager_jobs would look like this:

```
ManagerID | JobID
==========|======
    4     |   2
    3     |   2
    4     |   1
```

As you can see, Manager_jobs can encode that a Manager has multiple jobs assigned and vice versa.

This approach, of course, requires you to have some form of primary key for both data tables.

Comment: yes i mean sql = "INSERT INTO Add(manager_id,jobId,date) VALUES (?,?,?);"; but after that you have to EXTRACT the manager_id of john and jobID of jobA and jobB to insert into the Add table. if not how does the program knows what values to insert for add table?

Comment: Well, sqlite gives you the key of your last insert. http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html

So, if you ask it for the last insert ID right after you inserted the Job/Manager, you get the ID you need to insert into Add.